# clear cell value in gridview templatefield when clicked on the cell

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

i am using a gridview control with template fields inside as shown in the code below. where users update the values in the gridview control; my requirement is to clear the contents of the cell when users click on that cell. in other words, when a user clicks on a cell, the cell should clear itself and users should be able to enter a value. If the user does not enter value after clicking a cell and clicks somewhere else, i need to get the original value back into the cell.

i did a lot of research and found post here on SO that suggests using Java Script; i tried that(it is shown bold in the code below) but it is not working. any thoughts on what i am doing wrong? thanks in advance.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Q1" SortExpression="CYQ1">
            <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="CYTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CYQ1") %>' Width="50"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="CYQ1TextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="20" Width="50" 
                Text = '<%# Bind("CYQ1","{0:0.##}") %>' Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt"> 

                    **<script type="text/javascript">
                        var txtsearch = document.getElementById("CYQ1TextBox");
                        txtsearch.onfocus = function () {
                            if (this.value == "Group Name..") {
                                this.value = "";
                            }
                        };

                        txtsearch.onblur = function () {
                            if (this.value.length == 0) {
                                this.value = "Group Name...";
                            }
                        }
                    </script>**      

              </asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>        
              <HeaderStyle Width="40px" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt"/>
          </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this which using jQuery

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Q1" SortExpression="CYQ1" ItemStyle-CssClass="ValueCell">
            <ItemTemplate >
              <asp:Label ID="CYQ1Label" runat="server" MaxLength="20" Width="50" 
                Text='<%# Bind("CYQ1","{0:0.##}") %>' />
              <asp:TextBox ID="CYQ1TextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="20" Width="50" 
               Text='<%# Bind("CYQ1","{0:0.##}") %>' style="display:none" /> 
            </ItemTemplate>        
          </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note :

- CSSclass for each cell.
- Hide Textbox with display:none
- No Edit Template
- Should include jQuery one time only per page, and before any jQuery code

  ```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
          $('td.ValueCell span').click(function () {
              var span = $(this);
              span.hide();
              var box = span.siblings('input:text');
              box.val(span.text());
              box.show();
          });

          $('td.ValueCell input:text').blur(function () {
              var box = $(this);
              box.hide();
              var span = box.siblings('span');

              if (box.val() == '') {
                  box.val(span.text());
              }else {
                  span.text(box.val());
              };
              span.show();
          });
      });
  </script>
  ```

On code behind, you can read values from textbox's on some button click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in Grid1.Rows)
    {
        // Textbox will presist values entered by user (label will not)  
        var box = (TextBox)row.FindControl("CYQ1TextBox");


    }
}
```